# NPER excel function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, finance

Has anybody figured out how to use NPER excel function to SQL? Use case is that I am trying to find the remaining terms of an acct in SQL.

Fields:
Current_principalbalance - PV
Current_interestrate/100/12 - RATE
Current_paymentamount- PMT
No types in data
no FV in data

I tried:

```
    Use NLS
go

declare @fv   float
declare @rate float 
declare @Pmt  float
declare @k    float 
declare @pv   float

set @fv=0
set @rate=(select (current_interest_rate/100/12) from loanacct)
set @pmt= (select amortized_payment_amount from loanacct_payment)
set @pv = (select current_principal_balance from loanacct)
set @k=1

select  Log10((-@Fv * (@Rate / @k) + @Pmt) 
        / (@Pmt + (@Rate / @k) * @Pv)) 
        / Log10(1 + @Rate) as nper

        from loanacct a, loanacct_detail b, loanacct_setup c, loan_class d, loan_group e, loanacct_payment f

where a.acctrefno = b.acctrefno
and b.acctrefno = c.acctrefno
and a.loan_class2_no = d.codenum
and e.loan_group_no = a.loan_group_no
and f.acctrefno = a.acctrefno
and e.loan_group_no = 55
and a.loan_number IN (66515,67214,65980)
```

but now i get the error: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, an a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Tried NPER = Log((-@Fv * (@Rate / k) + @Pmt) / (@Pmt + (@Rate / k) * @Pv)) / Log(1 + @Rate) but it did not get me the right numbers

Comment: do you have a case where it worked and one where it didnt

Comment: You have edited the question!

Comment: The error you get is different from the question you have asked which is "how to calculate NPER in SQL"

Comment: Thank you for the direction George! So i used your logic and it gives me the right answer now but i ran into some problems when trying to replace it with my fields

Answer (score 1):

Since NPER is a forumla it would be possible to implement it in SQL since the operators for a formula would almost always be supported in databases

When using "Log" in your query, the natural logarithm is considered, and nper uses the Log to base 10. Therefore the formula should be altered as

```
select Log10((-@Fv * (@Rate / @k) + @Pmt) 
        / (@Pmt + (@Rate / @k) * @Pv)) 
        / Log10(1 + @Rate) as nper
```

Here is a test case which compares the value from excel nper function and one from the sql server database, that matches using your example..

--I have edited the datatypes to be float

```
declare @fv   float
declare @rate float 
declare @Pmt  float
declare @k    float 
declare @pv   float

set @fv=0
set @rate=15.99/100/12
set @pmt=-167.65
set @pv =1491.42
set @k=1
--In case the interests obtained at start of period then set @k as follows
--set @k = 1 + @rate

select Log10((-@Fv * (@Rate / @k) + @Pmt) 
        / (@Pmt + (@Rate / @k) * @Pv)) 
        / Log10(1 + @Rate) as nper
        
+------------------+
|       nper       |
+------------------+
| 9.53201056406188 |
+------------------+
```

Excel
=NPER(15.99/100/12, -167.65,1491.42,0)

[image]

Here is a dbfiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f470cee443e10647f83d6e640129d51

Comment: db fiddle link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c383f4c4d4f45128879175a422573f1e

Comment: Hi George thank you for your help but that still does not calculate what i need..

Comment: Here is an example: EXCEL = NPER(15.99/100/12, -167.65,1491.42) and this answer gives me 10

Comment: Used your formula: Log10((-0 * ((a.current_interest_rate/100/12) / 1) + f.amortized_payment_amount) 
        / (f.amortized_payment_amount + ((a.current_interest_rate/100/12) / 1) * a.current_principal_balance)) 
        / Log10(1 + (a.current_interest_rate/100/12)) as nper, and this returned -7.47350527170401 instead of 10

Comment: I get the answer for  NPER(15.99/100/12, -167.65,1491.42) as 9.53201056406188. This is because the answer depends on the datatype being used in excel. If its without any decimals it would show up as 10. I have edited the answer to make use of floats and the values match

Comment: This is what im using: Log10((-0 * ((a.current_interest_rate/100/12) / 1) + f.amortized_payment_amount) 
        / (f.amortized_payment_amount + ((a.current_interest_rate/100/12) / 1) * a.current_principal_balance)) 
        / Log10(1 + (a.current_interest_rate/100/12)) as nper,

Comment: I declared the variables as float and set the variables to the fields in front of the query and i end up getting 7.8037578288100208768

Comment: what were the input values you have used to get 7.8037578288100208768. ie @rate,@pmt,@fv,@pv,@k

Comment: i get 10 now if i used the same numbers, but when i set it with actual fields i get a subquery error and NULL values

Comment: you need to be specific and whittle down your problem to a simple test. NPER is a formula and for a set of inputs the results has to be identical

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication George, I got the logic down and now i am trying to replace the numbers with actual fields from a table... ie rate = current_interest_rate, pv = current_principal_balance, pmt = amortized_payment_amount etc

Answer (score 1):

For this use case this was my solution and it works perfect to NPER function in excel:

```
    declare @fv   float
declare @k    float 

set @fv=0
set @k=1

select CEILING(Log10((-@Fv * ((current_interest_rate/100/12) / @k) + -amortized_payment_amount) 
        / (-amortized_payment_amount + ((current_interest_rate/100/12) / @k) * current_principal_balance)) 
        / Log10(1 + (current_interest_rate/100/12))) as nper
```